# MUC room is locked with default installation of tigase

Tags: xmpp, smack, tigase, muc

I have installed tigase7.0.2 with basic configurations.

Now i am performing MUC using installed server with following codes:

For Creating Room

```
MultiUserChatManager manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
MultiUserChat muc = MainActivity.manager.getMultiUserChat("myroom@muc." + connection.getServiceName());
```

For joining Room

```
    muc = MainActivity.manager.getMultiUserChat("myroom@muc." + connection.getServiceName());
    muc.join(connection.getUser().split("@")[0]);
    muc.addMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
   @Override
   public void processMessage(final Message message) {
           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
          Toast.makeText(UserListActivity.this, message.getFrom() + ":" + message.getBody(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
       });
    }
   });
```

When i am joining the room following message is appears in Toast.

```
: Room is locked. Please configure.
: Welcome! You created new Multi User Chat Room. Room is locked now. Configure it please!
```

When i joining room it gives following error in the log.

Answer (score 0):

When you first create a MUC room, it is "locked" until you configure it.  There are two ways to configure the room: either accept the default configuration (this is called an "instant" room), or specify the configuration you want.

Creating an instant room is described in [section 10.1.2 of XEP-0045](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#createroom-instant):

```xml
<iq from='crone1@shakespeare.lit/desktop'
    id='create1'
    to='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'
    type='set'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner'>
    <x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='submit'/>
  </query>
</iq>
```

That is, send an IQ message with type `set`, containing a `query` element in the MUC owner namespace, containing just a form "submit".  This is also mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15490352/113848).

To use a specific configuration for the room, see [section 10.1.3 of XEP-0045](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#createroom-reserved).  First request the configuration form to find out which options are supported, and then fill it out with the settings you need.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28824927/113848) describes how to create a room that is public and persistent.